# How to check if the value of an element has been changed?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I check if the value of a `Html.EditorFor` element has changed using Javascript or jQuery?

```text
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddressPhysical1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "AddrPhys1", @onload = "TrackChanges(this.value)" } })
```

```js
$(document).ready(function TrackChanges() {
  var address = $('#AddressPhysical1').val();

  $('#AddressPhysical1').keyup(function() {
    if ($('#AddressPhysical1').val() != content) {
      content = $('#AddressPhysical1').val();
      alert('Content has been changed');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You have given the input `id = "AddrPhys1"`, so for a start you need to replace `$('#AddressPhysical1')` with `$('#AddrPhys1')`. And where have you declared `content` (or did you mean `address`)?

Comment: Also note the `TrackingChanges()` function is not in scope of the `onload` attribute, so that will be causing an error.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function TrackChanges()` => this is not a proper way to declare `onload` event handler function. Just use `function TrackChanges()` and put the `$(document).ready()` inside it.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out @StephenMuecke , it seems to be getting the value now. What I am trying to do is show a list of all the changed values in a popup before hitting the submit button.

Comment: Then the correct approach would be to handle your forms `.submit()` event, then check the `defaultValue` vs the `value` or each input (certainly not in a `.keyup()` event)